# Website or program that creates puzzles from blunders in your past games

Tags: analysis, learning, software, problems, programming

I'm looking for a website or program that would look at your past games on Lichess or chess.com and find moves that you played that were blunders and create puzzles around those

Comment: Slight tangent, but this is the premise of chesstempo.com [no affiliation], except instead of drawing from your games, it simply pulls from public repositories, and creates puzzles based on material shifts or similar concepts after running analysis on those games.

Comment: Actually, https://chesstempo.com/ can create puzzles from your own games played within chesstempo.

Comment: I put in a feature request ticket for Lichess [not affiliated] https://github.com/ornicar/lila/issues/8250 but the developers indicated on discord if I wanted the feature it might be easier for me to create me own website that uses their API opposed to waiting for the ticket to be filled since they get so many

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/boh6tg/creating_puzzles_based_on_your_blunder_in_lichess/) reddit post which has two comments which answer this question.

[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/boh6tg/creating_puzzles_based_on_your_blunder_in_lichess/engc0sq?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

```
https://tactics.bitcrafter.net/
```

This is essentially exactly what I was looking for and bonus points in that I think I found [their github](https://github.com/nathanj/lichess-tactics) that has their code which seems shockingly simple

[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/boh6tg/creating_puzzles_based_on_your_blunder_in_lichess/engj7v1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

```
I made something like that, both open source


http://chesstacticsgenerator.vitomd.com/

Description: Generate chess tactics from your own lichess games. This is based in the info that lichess generates (blunders, mistakes)


https://github.com/vitogit/pgn-tactics-generator

Description: Generate chess puzzles / tactics from a pgn file (this uses a python library & stockfish to evaluate blunders)
```

(Note, I am not affiliated with any of the links / software / repositories)

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I am not affiliated with them in any way.

Comment: That seems very fair. I have edited my answer to include that. I will try to do so on future posts as well

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of a single program that does all that. I do it myself with following steps. I save most of my games in a pgn file. The interesting ones, esp. my losses, are analyzed by Stockfish. The "blunder threshold" is your choice, typically 3 - 5 pawns or more. With Notepad++ text editor I enter the FEN of the position in a pgn file, of course preceded by the tag line [SetUp "1"]. Answer is best line of Stockfish. I skip positions that are cooked by good alternative choices.
When 50 - 100 puzzle positions are accumulated I transfer the pgn file to my Android phone & tablet. I display them with iChess but many other apps handle pgn files.

Answer (score 9):

Lichess has the "learn from your mistakes" feature, which can be used to play your significantly bad moves in a game as a puzzle.

From your profile, select a variant/time control on the left, then click "view the games" in the top right.  Click on a game, go to the analysis board, and at the bottom, in the "computer analysis" tab, click "request a computer analysis".  Once you've done that, a button will appear on the bottom right for you to "learn from your mistakes".

With a free account you're limited to a few analyses a day, (I think it's around 30), and this is a bit of a manual process, but it's relatively close to what you have in mind.  Also, unless you're on really short time controls, (for which puzzle rush would be better training than learn from your mistakes), you're not likely completing more than 30 games a day, so you can catch up with yourself at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Lichess generates [puzzles from your games](https://lichess.org/training/of-player) automatically.

Comment: "Play rapid and classical games to increase your chances of having a puzzle of yours added!" - I don't believe this is the same thing. I believe these would just be normal puzzles. I'm looking for essentially their 'learn from your mistakes' feature, but for all games.

Comment: I mean, it's exactly what you asked for. Apparently you haven't played many games, so Lichess hasn't found any puzzles in them yet. You can see my puzzles [here](https://lichess.org/training/of-player?name=kamekura).


But looking at your [comment above](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34251/website-or-program-that-creates-puzzles-from-blunders-in-your-past-games/34284?noredirect=1#comment54329_34251), I see that you're looking for a variant of the "learn from your mistakes feature". That's not the same as puzzles, so you might want to clarify that in your question here.

Comment: Cannot edit my comment for some reason so I'm adding a correction and a clarification here: 1) correction: it's not *exactly* what you're looking for since a puzzle can be generated even if you didn't blunder

Comment: I do appreciate your answer (I upvoted it). Specifically I was looking for a way to quiz on blunders in my games to try and find common themes for mistakes I've made. So it's less of looking for puzzles from my games and more specifically trying to analyze blunders I make and try to improve

Comment: 2) clarification: you might already be aware of this, but just in case: Learn from your Mistakes lets you find a better move, but often there are *multiple* good moves, while puzzles (almost) always have a unique answer.  Also,  sometimes a good move in LfyM is simply a move that doesn't make you lose (as opposed to the blunder you did play), while in Lichess puzzles the correct answer is almost always a move that results in either mate or gaining substantial material.

Comment: Ya, I'm aware of that feature and essentially I'm looking for that same feature, but randomized across my games.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120157/discussion-between-kamekura-and-nanotek).

Answer (score 2):

I built the online [tool](https://www.chessflashcards.com/create/puzzle-generator/) that does exactly that.
To save time, it processes up to 50 games at once and does not require you to run analysis of each game first on chess.com or lichess.org.

The added bonus is that puzzles are converted to flashcards compatible with open source flashcard software [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/). I chose Anki because I found out that I can practice reviewing puzzles using spaced repetition that I have complete control of. In other words with Anki flashcards I can tweak the spaced repetition algorithm to fit my needs and time constraints.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mobile app called ChessAlly (you can find it on the Apple app store) that allows you to create puzzles from your own games on Lichess or Chess.com
It uses Lichess or Chess.com API to fetch your games and uses Stockfish on the backend to create puzzles from positions where you could gain or not lose at least 0.5 point

Comment: And now re-hosted as a web app https://www.chessally.com/solve-puzzles

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this and after not finding something suitable, I have set up a small, free app called the Chess Blunder Trainer on my own.

You can find it in the Google Play Store via https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cbt.chess_blunder_trainer

You import your games as PGN. It identifies blunder moves and generates puzzles from the position. Like this, you can replay the position and try to identify better moves. Have fun with it and let me know what you think!

[image: Chess Blunder Trainer App]

You can find out more about the app here as well: [www.chessblundertrainer.com](https://www.chessblundertrainer.com)

Answer (score 0):

[AimChess](https://aimchess.com/) does exactly that for both Lichess and chess.com.